# cf set-org-quota get the error: You are not authorized to perform the requested action

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am trying to assign a new quota to the org using the "cf set-org-quota" command, but I keep getting "You are not authorized to perform the requested action" The user I used is already an OrgManager, OrgAuditor, a Space developer, and a Space manager. I have also tried to assign the same user as Cloud_Controller.admin following this link: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/uaa/uaa-user-management.html#creating-admin-users. Using "uaac user get" command shows the following command:

```
uaac user get admindemo:

  id: e9598aef-6bb6-4419-881a-b0480095ee4f
  meta
    version: 0
    created: 2023-08-17T12:37:17.415Z
    lastmodified: 2023-08-17T12:37:17.415Z
  name
  emails: 
  -
    value: hide because of privacy
    primary: false
  groups: 
  -
    value: ba552af5-ed6c-4510-8ca4-f563ebea3e92
    display: approvals.me
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: d6a655f7-32c2-40f7-a0b5-a5f2508e7f47
    display: profile
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: ef728e05-1c33-4f4b-bbf1-2e6eee1f1f5f
    display: cloud_controller_service_permissions.read
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 28d315f8-2fe5-4a50-9b6c-628775427743
    display: cloud_controller.admin
    type: DIRECT
```

So, I am figuring out what other role I should assign to the user to assign the quota to the org. Any suggestion you can give me will be helpful.
Thank you